# Unable to merge files using RequireOptimizer

Tags: requirejs, build-process

I want to merge files using the Require Optimizer, which I'm not able to do because of an error:

Here's the folder structure:

```
-build
  -r.js
  -build.js
-server
  -app.js
  -src
    -clientConnectivity
      -Upload.js
```

Here's build.js

```
({
    baseUrl: "..",
    paths: {
        uploadManager: "./server/src/clientConnectivity/Upload"
    },
    include: uploadManager,
    name: "server/app",
    out: "main-built.js"
})
```

Here's the command passed and the error received:

```
C:\Users\Anjan\WebstormProjects\RequireOptimizerTest\build>node r.js -o build.js
Error: Error: Build file C:/Users/Anjan/WebstormProjects/RequireOptimizerTest/build/build.js is malformed: ReferenceError: uploadManager is not defined
    at Function.build.createConfig (C:\Users\Anjan\WebstormProjects\RequireOptimizerTest\build\r.js:26541:23)
```

Here are the imports in app.js. I expect the Require Optimizer to read these imports in app.js and accordingly merge the called files.

```
import express = require('express');
import http = require('http');
import path = require('path');
import fs = require('fs');
import uploadModule = require('./src/clientConnectivity/Upload');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fixed example:

```
({
    baseUrl: "..",
    name: "server/app",
    out: "main-built.js",
    mainConfigFile : 'path/to/main.js',
    findNestedDependencies: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed this problem. Although, I was hoping I would not have to define any paths at all. The optimizer could follow the import/require statements and obtain all js files referred to in them recursively and then include them in a single file. How can that be achieved?

Comment: @EternallyCurious You don't have to. You may specify your main.js

Comment: @EternallyCurious Updated example

Comment: I don't have a main.js in the server directory. What should I put in that file?

Comment: @EternallyCurious main.js is a file, where your requirejs config is specified. Don't know exactly where you have it.

Comment: I don't have a require config file yet and this is a fresh project. Part of my effort is to see if RequireJS or Optimizer can recursively trace require statements in each js file - so I can avoid writing config files and just refer to the file at the starting point. In this case that file is app.js. Substituting "app.js" in place of main.js is creating an error.

Comment: @EternallyCurious Not sure if this will work, but try to add ```finedNestedDependencies``` option to your build.js. Updated an example.